# Problems with moving my site to another server - WSOD with unfamiliar errors

Tags: migrations

I've transferred a site from one server to another (both using Webmin's backup and restore facility).

Everything appears to have transferred across fine, except for when I try to access my site, I get the WSOD. I enabled error reporting and get the following error. Unfortunately, I'm unable to comprehend what it's telling me.

> Warning: Table 'id0063_BTG.users' doesn't exist query: SELECT u.*, s.*
>   FROM users u INNER JOIN sessions s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid =
>   'dc0n9e93lvckbmskv5frobirn2' in
>   /home/id0063/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 128
>
> Warning: Table 'id0063_BTG.system' doesn't exist query: SELECT name,
>   filename, throttle FROM system WHERE type = 'module' AND status = 1
>   AND bootstrap = 1 ORDER BY weight ASC, filename ASC in
>   /home/id0063/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 128
>
> Warning: Table 'id0063_BTG.url_alias' doesn't exist query: SELECT
>   COUNT(pid) FROM url_alias in
>   /home/id0063/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 128

I checked the Apache error log and found this:

> [Tue Jul 19 16:40:24 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: call
>   /home/id0063/public_html/index.php with wrapper
>   /home/id0063/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/intl.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php/modules/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas where I can start?

Comment: Make sure that your PHP version and extension versions are right/matching.

Comment: Try running a `drush updatedb` and also make sure your settings.php is pointing to the correct database. Failing that, a `drush rr` (registry rebuild) may be required if modules have moved for some reason.

Comment: at the risk of sounding silly is the settings.php updated with any possible changes in the database settings such as credentials, port or host and are the users and url_alias tables present in the newly restored DB id0063_BTG? [intl.so](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) appears to be Internationalization extension and to the naked eye doesn't appear related to the database errors..

Answer (score 1):

When I'm migrating websites I use the [Backup & Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module. You should give it a try.

If the problem persists, look for differences between the two servers: PHP version, Apache version, MySQL version, etc.
Also check your user permissions on the new server.

Comment: PHP, Apache and MySQL are both the same. User permissions don't appear to be out of the ordinary.

Is there any indication as to what the problem is? I'm slightly more interested - at the moment - in what is causing the error, rather than how it might be prevented in future.

Answer (score 0):

That message indicates your new server is missing the database (or at least some tables, but more likely all of them).

You'll need to copy the database from your old site to the new one.  Step-by-step migration instructions are in the [d.o. handbook](https://drupal.org/node/776864).